What does a green reticle mean, and why can't I shoot?
I came across this presumed enemy banging his head into a wall

and for some reason, when I aim at them the three lines/dots (the reticle) turn green (they're normally blue) and I can't fire. When I don't aim at them, the reticle turns blue again.
What is the reticle turning green supposed to signify? Why can't I shoot?

Steam question about similar situation.
Seems like it's just what happens when you aim at NPCs. Probably it's like in Half-Life 2 where it's both preventing you from interrupting a cutscene and also preventing you from wasting bullets / being cruel.

I hate it when games don’t allow me to indulge in wanton murder for fun (/s).

Also, yeah, when I continued a bit past them they dropped dead, so they turned out not to be an enemy after all.
